# creating a pie charts using string like 'used' and 'not used'

Tags: charts, highcharts

actually I'm doing this internship for my school i need to use the information on a very large database to actually draw a pie chart on the website i am developing for them. they want to know the number of ports used versus not used also they want to know for each equipment the number of ports used versus not used in such  way that any new data entered can automatically change the graph. the only values present are "used" and "not used" how do i use these information to draw the pie chart?. thank you

Comment: you can achieve it by using `chart.js`

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't list the database structure here is a generic SQL query:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY status
```

Here `status` refers to the column that states "used" or "not used" and `yourTable` is, well, the table that contains this info. Once you have this you can create a pie chart in highcharts via:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Ports in use'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'used',
            y: 56 // from the SQL query
        }, {
            name: 'not used',
            y: 24, // from the SQL query
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
        }]
    }]
});
```

Live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fo99rnb7/).

To have this chart updated I would recommend a timer to re-query the database on an interval and refresh the data in the chart. Because you do not mention any other dependencies I am just going to link out to how to [update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData) a highcharts chart. If you provide more info like what libraries you are using or what framework the webpage is using then a more detailed answer can be provided.